# Как синхронизировать доступ к общему массиву?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Друзья, пишу на nodejs с недавних пор. Сейчас появился следующий вопрос:

Есть массив с элементами. Данный массив меняют функции-обработчики нескольких событий. Возникнуть события могут в любой момент и в теории могут наложатся друг на друга. Насколько я понимаю, может случится, что один обработчик может начать читать элемент в процессе изменения/удаления его другим обработчиком. Как синхронизировать этот процесс? Может быть в какой-то try/catch оборачивать? Обычно существует какая-то абстракция, синхронизирующая такой доступ - флажок/палочка или канал. А в js что-то не могу с ходу даже констатации такой проблемы найти. Может быть тут всё сделано на уровне движка уже? Не хочется, чтобы приложение упало из-за  такого недосмотра с моей стороны.

Буду рад любым примерам и ссылкам. Очень хочется получить что-то максимально модное на данный момент. Заранее благодарен :-)

Comment: _Насколько я понимаю, может случится, что один обработчик может начать читать элемент в процессе изменения/удаления его другим обработчиком._ неее, такое не может случится, все в одном потоке выполняется

Comment: js - однопоточный (если не брать во внимание сервисные потоки), т.е. вышеописанной проблемы не может произойти.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: кое где есть SharedArrayBuffer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer, только с ним, насколько мне известно, возможны настоящие заморочки с concurrency

Comment: Для справки: в node.js существует возможность запускать несколько параллельных воркеров [node-cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Однако и там эту проблему получить сложно. Без использования общей(shared) памяти можно не переживать.